# How to give user permissions on ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, hosting

i have an ubuntu server and i give hosting to some users and i use the next command to create users and their ftp accounts:
sudo adduser nameofthepage

This command creates a directory with the name of the page in the "/home" directory where users can put the files of their web pages.

But i have a serious problem, when users log in to the server with their ftp accounts they can go a directory up of the /home directory and see all the directories of the server, how can i limit it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what ftpd are you using ?

Comment: Normally what you want is achieved by a `chrooted SFTP` only setup or some restricted shell like `rssh`. Do you have to stay with a less secure `FTP` setup?

Answer (score 1):

If /home is owned by root, which it probably is... you can always revoke read access for "others" on the /home directory itself.

```
sudo chmod o-r /home
```

Answer (score 1):

If your concerned about that level of access, you might be better off using some kind of chroot or jail for users.  There's pam_chroot and rssh that can be used to restrict users, and I'm sure some more jail options as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, you should use virtual users for that. Look at mysql-pam.d you could have one database for ssh/ftp/other logins + disk quota  or anything else just in one table. Check yours architection and scalability.