# How can i add ftp accounts on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to give user permissions on ubuntu server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/257079/how-to-give-user-permissions-on-ubuntu-server)

Hi, i've a serious problem creating FTP accounts on my Ubuntu server:

I create a new ftp user account with the following command: "sudo adduser username" and it creates automatically a folder where the user is going to put their files, but when the user login through FTP he can go up a directory to the root directory and do whatever he wants, the big question is "How can i limit the access of the user and let him only to see his folder and don't permit to go to another up directory?"

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are options in /etc/vsftpd.conf to help make vsftpd more secure. Users can be limited to their home directories by uncommenting:

chroot_local_user=YES

Answer (score 0):

You've not mentioned what FTP server software you're using (vsftpd, proftpd?) but most FTP servers have the ability to 'jail' users to their own home directory.

Proftpd achieves this using the 'DefaultRoot' options in the configuration file. See http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_DefaultRoot.html